# Drying Li2CO3 without vaccum

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, drying

I am looking for drying Li2CO3 without a vacuum oven, simply because we do not have one.
I did not find anything in the literature, or I am overthinking it? Just 100 °C overnight in a normal oven, and afterward simply store it in a vacuum desiccator.

Comment: What about sufficiently strong desiccants?  $\ce{P4O10}$ or $\ce{Mg(ClO4)2}$. Even weaker should do. $\ce{CaCl2}$ ? $\ce{KOH}$ or $\ce{NaOH}$ ?

Comment: I would be careful with P4O10 as a Lux-Flood acid-base reaction could occur. The others look good.